SQL Server "BCP Error SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0 , Unable to open BCP host data-file" creating file on same server, different folder
I am trying to create and write out a file to a new directory on the same file server, but different file share.
I have researched questions already on Stack Overflow and other forums, nothing has yet to work.
I am using SQL Server Management Studio v 19.0 preview 2.
I have full control on the share that is failing "gillis$" file share from below, along with modify, Read & Execute, List folder contents, Read, Write.
I have only modify, Read & Execute, List folder contents, Read, Write, on the share that is working.  Same exact code, just different destination share on the same file server.
When I run using bcp (code will be below)  I receive 2 errors
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file
Here is the basics of my code. ##FinalChem is a global temp table.  The commented out line to public$\epicor\data works fine.  the line gillis$\LisaTest\ fails.  We use this code all the time to the public share to create files
declare @CMD varchar(8000)
declare @FileName varchar (100)
declare @FilePathOut varchar(100)

select @FileName = 'Chemical Use Report.csv' 

select @FilePathOut = '\\server1\gillis$\LisaTest\' -- errors
--Select @FilePathOut =  '\\server1\public$\epicor\data\EHS Chemical Report\' works fine

SELECT @CMD = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM ##FinalChem" queryout "'+ @FilePathOut + @FileName + '" -c -t, -T -S' + @@SERVERNAME;  

exec master..xp_cmdshell @CMD


I have full control on the share xp_cmdshell runs stuff not as you but rather as sql server user (or proxy if you have that), so whatever that account is, it should have access to the share

You can try to add PRINT @CMD; to your T-SQL. After that open a command prompt as Administrator, and execute its outcome directly for testing.

Thanks both.  I did use the following.  Surprised I have 2 records, from **Exec xp_cmdshell 'whoami.exe'  **  one for the user I expect and one record NULL;    I tested with the bcp command from a command prompt on the sql server and it ran successfully.  it is not running from SSMS

I will test next week when our prod database user is added to the group vs the whoami user.  thank you!
